# What exactly is the text height GetTextExtentPoint returns?

Tags: windows, gdi

On Windows, GetTextExtentPoints and friends return a SIZE structure that contains the height and width of a given string. I wonder what the height is exactly, e.g. the font height with or without external leading or the actual height of the string. The latter would mean that the height value depends on the actual string. E.g. "mmm" would have another height than "Aq".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried it: *GetTextExtentPoints* returns the font size including internal leading but excluing external leading, i.e. the cell size. This value does not depend on the actual string. (It does however for the text width obviously.)